# Keep JS from creating exception objects

Tags: javascript, exception

So i have situation where *I have to save the solution from a giant formula (calculation) to a variable and i know for sure that this will often have no solution so*

I will use a try catch clause. And I can not calculate it twice because it would be, *among possible other things,* much too long (timewise).

But from what I know, with every catch, **an exception object (etc) will get created. Is it possible to keep this from happening** (some command or similar)**?**

Because I know for sure I will never need these because I know why it is impossible sometimes, but this automatic behavior would obviously cause unnecessary stack and processor (and that way runTIME)  -usage.

*Or is this default behavior not the case for js?*

Comment: *If not, then that’s a bummer but please just tell me if, i don’t want any ‚why‘ question since this is a simple and clear question in the end:)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But from what I know, with every catch, an exception object (etc) will get created...

That's incorrect. An `Error` object will only be created if an error is thrown, not just because you have a `catch` block in your code. (And technically, in JavaScript, you can throw other things, they don't have to be `Error` instances, though when the browser or JavaScript engine throws something, it's always an `Error` object [directly or indirectly via a subclass].) If an error *is* created and thrown, and your code doesn't keep it, it'll immediately be eligible for garbage collection anyway. Creating and garbage collecting a single object is not a significant effort.

Comment: Ok so it is NOT possible. Regarding the ‚catch‘ I meant ‚when caught‘. Thanks.